# Can we downgrade version number while updating new version to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, versioning

I know it sounds strange but it is demand of my managers, earlier version of app on App Store is 2.2 but, now they want to upload new version 2.1.1. I want to ask is it possible. Please guide

Update: A new problem arises here, now App Store connect not allowing to create new version because

current live version: 2.21
new version created: 2.1.2 (Apple not allowing to upload on this        version as higher version already live, gave error msg)
Now, want to create new version 2.21.1 but how no option to add new version now. Got stuck badly, please guide what can be done here.

Comment: No — new version numbers are required to be higher.

Comment: no you can't do this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Apple allowed to use 2.1.2 not 2.1.1 and my current app version is 2.21, strange

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: @DroidGEEK With Apple anything possible, it allowed to create 2.1.2 but while uploading gave error that " a later version has been closed, please choose a different version". They should not allow to create 2.1.2 while creating new version number as given while creating 2.1.2

Comment: It is a bug from Apple, now 2.1.2 will never be deleted from App Store connect

Comment: @iPhone7, creating a build with 2.1.2 on your Mac takes place locally, no interaction involved with App Store Connect till now, while in Uploading, it verifies your credentials and other info related to your build. That is why it gives errors while uploading.

Comment: @DroidGEEK I understand that but I said it's Apple's bug because on App Store connect it allowed to create the new version 2.1.2 but through Xcode not allowed to submit build for 2.1.2.